# Ant cannot find the class

Tags: ant

I am starting out with ant and trying an example in which a java class is run from the ant build script.

Here is the java class:

```
public class NotifyAdministrator {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String email = args[0];
    System.out.println("Administrator "+email+"has been notified");

}

}
```

The Ant build file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="sample" basedir="." default="notify">
  <target name="notify">
    <java fork="false" failonerror="yes" classname="NotifyAdministrator">

      <arg line="admin@test.com"/>
    </java>
  </target>
</project>
```

Both files are in the same directory. I keep on getting the following error that the class NotifyAdministrator cannot be found

Answer (score 2):

Your NotifyAdministrators class is not on the classpath.

According to the [documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) you should add a classpath element to the java task like this:

```
<java classname="test.Main">
     <arg value="-h"/>
     <classpath>
       <pathelement location="dist/test.jar"/>
       <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
     </classpath>
</java>
```

ps. there is also a mail task [build in](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/mail.html) in ant:

```
<mail from="me"
  tolist="you"
  subject="Results of nightly build"
  files="build.log"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the NotifyAdministrator class in a package? if so it the class name property should contain the full path, including the package name

Comment: the class is not in a package and both files are in the same directory